# Cython - dictionary keys and values static type definition

Tags: python, cython

I want to use Cython to compile a Python module that works with a dictionary of which all keys are of type, say, integer (or no matter what other static and known type), and all values of type unicode (or other static and known).

Now, to speed it up, I can declare

```
cdef dict Dict
```

and also

```
cdef int k
cdef unicode v
```

But, can I make a static declaration of the whole "dict int->unicode" structure?

Thanks,

Comment: You could try defining a `struct` for your needs?

Answer (score 12):

I think the short answer is no. **Cython** is still using the built-in **Python** dictionary. It can take advantage of some optimisations if you declare the object as *dict*, but ultimately the *dict* has to be able to store objects of different types, and so you cannot specify the *key* or *value* types at compile-time. But you should check first to make sure that this is a bottleneck. **Python** dictionaries are fairly good.

Comment: Python `dict`s are fairly good, but if you're not careful, Cython can pessimize them a great deal. For example, if you declare your key type as `cdef int`, and write `for key in mydict: value = mydict[key]`, rather than `for key, value in mydict.items():`, Cython will blindly unpack from Python `int` to C `int` to store to `key`, then immediately turn around and repack from C `int` back to Python `int` to perform the `dict` lookup. It ends up slower than the original Python code (especially if the keys don't fall in the small int cache), which wouldn't have converted to C types and back.

Comment: I've seen real code of exactly the form I described where the goal was to sum the values in a `dict` with `int` keys and values, and they wrote `cdef int x, total = 0`, `for x in mydict: total += mydict[x]`. Cython didn't know the type of the `dict`s values and ended up generating code that performed the addition with Python, not C types, converted the keys to C `int` only to convert them back immediately, etc. The code ended up taking about 8x longer than if they'd skipped the keys and done `cdef int total, val`, `for val in mydict.values(): total += val`; suboptimal Cython can be terrible.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, what about `np.fromiter(mydict.values()).sum()`? would that be a better solution that will be done in C anyway? (nitpicking you since seems you've got some knowledge about it...)
*`itervalues()` if py2

Comment: @Ori5678: Actually, the better solution is just `sum(mydict.values())` (`itervalues` for Py2); CPython's built-in `sum` is already optimized for summing an iterable of `int`s with C level speed (it slows down if the sum would exceed the size of a C `long`, but remains correct, where `numpy` would become wrong), so there is really nothing to be gained from converting to a C level array of integers only to sum them when you could just convert and sum at once. You could match the speed of that with Cython if you were careful, but not improve on it meaningfully.